# Hangman Ruby Game - Why Does the Winning Message Delay and Saved Game Prompt Repeat?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, debugging, game-development

I  am developing a Hangman game as part of the Odin Project curriculum (https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/ruby-hangman).

The game utilizes a dictionary file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt) to randomly select a word between 5 and 12 characters in length for the player to guess. Players receive feedback on the number of incorrect guesses remaining, the correct letters chosen, and their positions within the word. The game allows players to guess a letter during each turn, and the display updates accordingly.

Additionally, players have the option to save their progress at the beginning of any turn. The program supports loading saved games to resume play from where it was left off.
Here is what I wrote:

```
require 'yaml'

class Hangman
  def initialize(file)
    saved_file_exist if File.exist?('save_game.yaml')

    @data = File.readlines(file)
    @word = select_word
    @array = Array.new(@word.size - 1) { '_' }
    @attempts_left = 100
    @incorrect_guesses = []
  end

  def saved_file_exist
    puts 'Do you want to load the saved game? (yes/no). Press enter if you have already done that'
    choice = gets.chomp.downcase
    return unless choice == 'yes'

    Hangman.load_game
  end

  def select_word
    guessed_word = @data.select { |word| word.strip.size >= 5 && word.strip.size <= 12 }
    guessed_word.sample
  end

  def guessing_selection
    puts 'Try guessing a letter from the secret word'
    guess = gets.chomp.downcase

    until guess.match?(/^[a-zA-Z]$/)
      puts 'Your input should be one letter and not a number'
      guess = gets.chomp.downcase
    end
    guess
  end

  def give_a_clue(array, word, guess)
    word.chars.each_with_index do |letter, index|
      array[index] = letter if letter == guess
    end

    array.join(', ')
  end

  def save_game
    File.open('save_game.yaml', 'w') do |file|
      file.puts self.to_yaml
    end
    puts 'Game saved successfully!'
  end

  def self.load_game
    saved_game_data = YAML.load(File.read('save_game.yaml'))
    saved_game = Hangman.new('words.txt') # Create a new instance of Hangman
    saved_game.yaml_initialize(saved_game_data) # Initialize the instance with saved data
    puts 'Game loaded successfully!'
    saved_game.play # Call play method on the instance
  end

  def to_yaml
    YAML.dump(
      {
        'word' => @word,
        'array' => @array,
        'attempts_left' => @attempts_left,
        'incorrect_guesses' => @incorrect_guesses
      }
    )
  end

  def yaml_initialize(map)
    @word = map['word']
    @array = map['array'].nil? ? Array.new(@word.size - 1) { '_' } : map['array']
    @attempts_left = map['attempts_left']
    @incorrect_guesses = map['incorrect_guesses']
  end

  def play_again
    puts "Current state: #{@array}"
    @attempts_left -= 1
    puts "Attempts left: #{@attempts_left}"
    puts "Incorrect guesses so far: #{@incorrect_guesses.join(', ')}"
    play
  end

  def keep_playing
    @guess = guessing_selection

    if @word.include?(@guess)
      give_a_clue(@array, @word, @guess)
    else
      @incorrect_guesses << @guess unless @incorrect_guesses.include?(@guess)
    end
    play_again
  end

  def delete_saved_game
    File.delete('save_game.yaml') if File.exist?('save_game.yaml')
    exit
  end

  def game_state
    if !@array.include?('_')
      puts "Congratulations, You won! The word is: #{@word}"
      delete_saved_game
    elsif @attempts_left.positive?
      keep_playing
    else
      puts "Game over! The word was: #{@word}"
      delete_saved_game
    end
  end

  def play
    puts "Type 'save' to save the game and exit, or continue with a letter guess."

    input = gets.chomp.downcase

    if input == 'save'
      save_game
      return
    end

    game_state
  end
end

hangman = Hangman.new('words.txt')
hangman.play
```

However, I am facing two specific challenges with my code:

Unexpected Prompt After Winning the Game: Upon winning the game, the program is expected to display a congratulatory message and terminate. However, instead, the program prompts the user to either save the game and exit or continue with another letter guess. Only after pressing a key does the program terminate.

Persistent Prompt When Loading Saved Games: When a saved game is available, the program prompts the user, "Do you want to load the saved game? (yes/no). Press enter if you have already done that." Even upon entering "yes," the prompt reappears, and the game only loads after pressing another key.

I have attempted various solutions to address these issues, but none have been successful. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving these challenges and ensuring the game functions as intended.

Comment: When you input the last character, `@array.include?('_')` will still evaluate to `false`, as you did not take out the guessed word yet, so your `if..elif` construction will jump into the `keep_playing` method. That method then ends with `play_again`, so you will be returned to the prompt. The rough idea here is to remove the character from the array before checking if it still has any characters in it left, and then decide whether to jump into the `play_again` branch or end the game

Comment: Note that you have implemented an indirect recursion (play→game_state →keep_playing→play_again→play). While this isn’t a huge issue, it might be easier to follow the code flow with a simple loop and an explicit break condition.